How to extract data from a Dell ECS with Azure Data Factory?
My client has a Dell ECS in their data center and this device is used to:

Store data in parquet format
Maintain aggregated data via Databrick's Delta Lake

I need to be able to extract (and later transform) both parquet and Delta Lake data using Azure Data Factory.
The parquet files seem like an easy task via Data Factory's filesystem (SMB) linked service.
The remaining data (Delta Lake) is puzzling me (since I am not a data engineer or application architect): which Data Factory feature should I use to extract it?
So far, I've tried unsuccessfully to create a Spark-linked service, but the test connection fails. I'm not sure which of its many ports should be targeted.
Note: A self-hosted integration runtime is already in place and operational.
I am looking for some advice or suggestions on where to start.

Can you provide your pipeline flow? and are your tables are azure databricks delta tables? and are they stored in ADLS gen2?

I'm unable to provide a pipeline flow, since this is one of the main premises of the question. As mentioned, the data is stored as parquet files inside a Dell ECS.

If your Delta tables are in the ADLS gen2 or blob storage, you can use ADF dataflow inline dataset Delta to copy or transform those.
Create a dataflow and in the source, select Inline dataset and from drop down click Delta type. Give the ADLS or Blob storage type linked service.

In the source options, select your delta table. Then, you can use the transformations as per your requirement. In the sink as well, select Inline dataset and use Delta type by giving ADLS or Blob linked service.
If your Delta tables are in local, you can try the approach of copying those to the ADLS or Blob to use the Dataflow (haven't tested it yet). Create a Binary dataset of your file system linked service and select your delta table folder. Also, create another binary dataset of ADLS type. Give the delta table name in the folder name.

Give these two datasets as source and sink of the Copy activity.

Now, the tables will be copied to the ADLS then you can use ADF dataflow or handle these as mentioned in the above.

Thanks, but that does not help. The source data is on premises, not Azure.
